# The page is not reading my image and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, liveserver

I finished my project, but although the extension Live Server is showing everything right, the images I added. When I open the page from the documents or from GitHub it is not reading SOME images. Does anyone recognize this error??

Ps: I'm just using HTML and CSS, making a portfolio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the prob, what you need to do is just upload the folder again on Github using (Check wheter you are uploading the correct folder and the files are linked correctly.). And than again download it. It may solve the problem.